# when unit testing controller i'm getting an assertion error

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing

i have created a basic CRUD api with spring boot.I have written test cases for the controller class,but i'm getting error when running the test.
**The code's i tried is given Below**

**model**

```
package com.example.crudrestapi.model;


import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String gstin;
    private float outstandingBalance;
}
```

**CrudController**

```
public class CrudController {

    @Autowired
    CustomerRepo customerRepo;
     @PostMapping("/customers")
    public @ResponseBody
    Customer postCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
        return customerRepo.save(customer);

    }


    @PutMapping("customers/{customerId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Customer> updateCustomer(@RequestBody Customer newCustomer, @PathVariable Long customerId) {

        Optional<Customer> optionalCustomer = customerRepo.findById(customerId);
        if (optionalCustomer.isPresent()){
            Customer c = optionalCustomer.get();
            if (newCustomer.getName() != null)
                c.setName(newCustomer.getName());
            if (newCustomer.getGstin() != null)
                c.setGstin(newCustomer.getGstin());
            if (newCustomer.getPhoneNumber() != null)
                c.setPhoneNumber(newCustomer.getPhoneNumber());
            if (newCustomer.getAddress() != null)
                c.setAddress(newCustomer.getAddress());
            if (newCustomer.getOutstandingBalance() != 0.0f)
                c.setOutstandingBalance(newCustomer.getOutstandingBalance());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(customerRepo.save(c), HttpStatus.OK);
        }else{
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }

    @DeleteMapping("customers/{customerId}")
    public String deleteCustomer(@PathVariable Long customerId) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        return customerRepo.findById(customerId)
                .map(customer -> {
                    customerRepo.delete(customer);
                    return "Success";
                })
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException());
    }
}
```

**CrudControllerTest**

```
package com.example.crudrestapi.controller;

import com.example.crudrestapi.model.Customer;
import com.example.crudrestapi.repository.CustomerRepo;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Optional;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasSize;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(CrudController.class)
class CrudControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    CustomerRepo customerRepo;


    @Test
    void postCustomer() throws Exception {
        Customer customer = Customer.builder().name("name").address("address").build();
        given(customerRepo.save(customer));
        mockMvc.perform(post("/customers")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(customer.toString())
                )
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }


   
    @Test
    void deleteCustomer() throws Exception {
        Customer customer = Customer.builder().name("name").address("address").build();
        given(customerRepo.findById(Long.parseLong("1"))).willReturn(Optional.empty());
        mockMvc.perform(delete("/customers/{customerId}", 1)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

*Error I'm Getting for POST api test*

```
    java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<400>
Expected :200
Actual   :400
<Click to see difference>


    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:59)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:627)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:196)
    at com.example.crudrestapi.controller.CrudControllerTest.postCustomer(CrudControllerTest.java:55)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
    Suppressed: org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at com.example.crudrestapi.controller.CrudControllerTest.postCustomer(CrudControllerTest.java:50)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, which is not supported
 3. you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction is completed

        at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:82)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:69)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:63)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:441)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.afterEach(SpringExtension.java:205)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterEachCallbacks$11(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:253)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks$12(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:269)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks$13(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:269)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:268)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAfterEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:252)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:137)
        ... 43 more

2020-12-27 18:23:51.851  INFO 10488 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'

Process finished with exit code -1
```

*Delete Api test case Error*

> java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404> Expected
> :200 Actual   :404

I'm failing in the above test cases.I don't know what is the issue.I'm Just a noob in testing environment .Any Suggestion would be a great help to me.

**EDIT**

*Post api Error*

```
 org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at com.example.crudrestapi.controller.CrudControllerTest.postCustomer(CrudControllerTest.java:52)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, which is not supported
 3. you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction is completed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the test. In particular, the way that you send the information in the body because you send an Object but the MockMvc needs a String with the JSON format to simulate a real request from outside of the API.

The way to fix the problem is:

```
   @Test
    void postCustomer() throws Exception {
        Customer customer = Customer.builder().name("name").address("address").build();
        given(customerRepo.save(customer));
        mockMvc.perform(post("/customers")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(asJsonString(customer))//Call to other method to transform an object to a JSON
                )
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    private String asJsonString(final Object obj) {
        try {
            return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(obj);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

The class **ObjectMapper** is from this package  ***com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper***

Comment: i tried the code but i'm getting error. i have added the error in above , can you check that.

Comment: The problem is you didn't put what the stub needs to do. This line  "given(customerRepo.save(customer));" need the action .wllReturn(xxxx);